# Compatibility of Flutter with Car Play and Android Auto

Tags: flutter, android-auto, carplay

I developed an app on Flutter and I'm looking at a way to link it with Car Play and Android Auto. For my understanding Flutter is not compatible yet. Anyone know if it will be in the future (if yes, when we should expect this)? Is there any turnaround I can look into?

Comment: Follow the official Flutter issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26801
(No statement has been made by the Flutter team yet since this issue was create back in Jan 2019) Please upvote it on Github to get more attention.

Answer (score 3):

## Flutter Apps are now compatible with Apple CarPlay!

[image: CarPlay for Flutter]

`flutter_carplay` aims to make it safe to use apps made with Flutter in the car by integrating with CarPlay. CarPlay takes the things you want to do while driving and puts them on the car’s built-in display. **Currently, it supports only iOS 14.0+.**

Feel free to like, star, comment, share, and contribute to support more!

- In pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carplay
- GitHub: https://github.com/oguzhnatly/flutter_carplay

Comment: No news about Android Auto?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter has yet to have Car Play and Android Auto support as of this writing. As previously mentioned in the comments, it's best to keep track for its updates in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26801).

Answer (score 0):

I got audio app working on carplay easily enough.  Based on

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_radio_player/example

And then using my apple developer account, setting entitlements to allow carplay, basically.  I cam add details if requested. Also, I used a mac/xcode to check things worked etc.

Android auto I can't yet get working.. funny that!

Comment: Is it possible to play an audio file in CarPlay? Did you use any package or did you write it without plugin?